# openSUSE zypper error - Valid metadata not found at specified URL, Repository type can't be determined

Tags: repository, artifactory, opensuse, sles, zypper

I have an `RPM repository` running on `JFrog Artifactory`. It's being used by CentOS and RHEL hosts, and I would also like to use it with my openSUSE hosts.

[This](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/RPM+Repositories) documentation from JFrog does not explicitly say that only yum clients are supported, and since they used the term `RPM repository`, to me it suggests that the repository should also work with `zypper` clients.

This is an [opensuse](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Creating_YaST_installation_sources#repomd.2Frpm_md.2FYUM_sources) document about `repomd/rpm md/YUM` sources, and a visual inspection of a repository on an openSUSE host created using the `createrepo` command looks consistent to the JFrog RPM repository layout.

```
opensuse:~ # ll /data/internalrepo/
total 1157456
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1185231772 Apr 22 08:54 myapp-server-2019.0.x86_64.rpm
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root        494 Apr 22 08:55 repodata
opensuse:~ # ll /data/internalrepo/repodata/
total 324
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1901 Apr 22 08:55 6a654dd3c11ae0f51efd9cd3fd09ccfdc3c48e988ab886c370e94f7f5bcdf3d1-primary.xml.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 315545 Apr 22 08:55 cfa28fb2383f1eec84d67bdb8a96d8d1ff66fa1917fb9ca5b5dfaea2569b559b-filelists.xml.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1840 Apr 22 08:55 e541d1abcfd503ea5b4d69cfcad74e57750969110429974db7651b2f4dcb44e6-other.xml.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1508 Apr 22 08:55 repomd.xml
opensuse:~ #
```

So at this point, I assume that pointing `zypper` to the `RPM repository` "should work" just fine.

However, when trying to point to the repository, there's an error `Repository type can't be determined` (#2 below). Here are all the steps to add the repository:

1. Add the repository using addrepo:

```
opensuse:~ # zypper addrepo https://myuser:mypassword@rpm.example.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/ myapp
Adding repository 'myapp' ..................................................................................................................................................[done]
Repository 'myapp' successfully added

URI         : https://myuser@rpm.example.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/
Enabled     : Yes
GPG Check   : Yes
Autorefresh : No
Priority    : 99 (default priority)

Repository priorities are without effect. All enabled repositories share the same priority.
opensuse:~ # zypper repos
Repository priorities are without effect. All enabled repositories share the same priority.

# | Alias                             | Name                              | Enabled | GPG Check | Refresh
--+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+-----------+--------
1 | myapp                          | myapp                          | Yes     | ( p) Yes  | No
2 | openSUSE-Leap-15.1-1              | openSUSE-Leap-15.1-1              | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
3 | openSUSE-Leap-15.1-Non-Oss        | openSUSE-Leap-15.1-Non-Oss        | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No
4 | openSUSE-Leap-15.1-Oss            | openSUSE-Leap-15.1-Oss            | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No
5 | openSUSE-Leap-15.1-Update         | openSUSE-Leap-15.1-Update         | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No
6 | openSUSE-Leap-15.1-Update-Non-Oss | openSUSE-Leap-15.1-Update-Non-Oss | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | No
opensuse:~ #
```

2. Try to refresh the repo:

```
opensuse:~ # zypper refresh myapp
Retrieving repository 'myapp' metadata ....................................................................................................................................[error]
Repository 'myapp' is invalid.
[myapp|https://myuser@rpm.example.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/] Valid metadata not found at specified URL
History:
 - [myapp|https://myuser@rpm.example.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/] Repository type can't be determined.

Please check if the URIs defined for this repository are pointing to a valid repository.
Skipping repository 'myapp' because of the above error.
Could not refresh the repositories because of errors.
opensuse:~ #
```

3. This is what the repo file looks like:

```
opensuse:~ # cat /etc/zypp/repos.d/myapp.repo
[myapp]
enabled=1
autorefresh=0
baseurl=https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/
type=NONE
opensuse:~ #
```

Manually downloading the `repomd.xml` file works fine.

```
opensuse:~ # curl -o repomd.xml --user myuser \
> https://rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/repodata/repomd.xml
Enter host password for user 'myuser':
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1393  100  1393    0     0   1625      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1623
opensuse:~ # cat repomd.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<repomd xmlns="http://linux.duke.edu/metadata/repo" xmlns:rpm="http://linux.duke.edu/metadata/rpm">
  <data type="other">
    <location href="repodata/f11b79e8b7cc5f4cc75851379d5e67d5f6434341-other.xml.gz"/>
    <checksum type="sha" pkgid="YES">f11b79e8b7cc5f4cc75851379d5e67d5f6434341</checksum>
    <size>2574</size>
    <timestamp>1585213347</timestamp>
    <open-checksum type="sha" pkgid="YES">de4ef8508be4c2088395e903e19159a7cad87199</open-checksum>
    <open-size>36635</open-size>
    <revision/>
  </data>
  <data type="filelists">
    <location href="repodata/5cdaa6b9a97e9092c9e68d9d8a1bb32530c8e4c7-filelists.xml.gz"/>
    <checksum type="sha" pkgid="YES">5cdaa6b9a97e9092c9e68d9d8a1bb32530c8e4c7</checksum>
    <size>962315</size>
    <timestamp>1585213345</timestamp>
    <open-checksum type="sha" pkgid="YES">726c2e5680556cdd38558f7a2a20bf38d2f0a128</open-checksum>
    <open-size>19862419</open-size>
    <revision/>
  </data>
  <data type="primary">
    <location href="repodata/cd85a1878f8c38c417e56a720c3ef4bc7f923eeb-primary.xml.gz"/>
    <checksum type="sha" pkgid="YES">cd85a1878f8c38c417e56a720c3ef4bc7f923eeb</checksum>
    <size>3005</size>
    <timestamp>1585213349</timestamp>
    <open-checksum type="sha" pkgid="YES">f3c3a178f18e7488eb0769dff6b3cd0def1144c4</open-checksum>
    <open-size>46509</open-size>
    <revision/>
  </data>
</repomd>opensuse:~ #
```

I tried to look at /var/log/zypper.log, but it's a little cluttered and I am not sure which ones are relevant:

```
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(repositories_in_file):289 repo file: /etc/zypp/repos.d/myapp.repo
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] IniParser.cc(parse):84 Start parsing /etc/zypp/repos.d/myapp.repo[g___]
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] IniParser.cc(parse):138 Done parsing /etc/zypp/repos.d/myapp.repo[_eF_]
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [Progress++] ProgressData.cc(report):88 {#7|/etc/zypp/repos.d/myapp.repo}END
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoFileReader.cc(repositories_in_stream):191 --------------------------------------
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoFileReader.cc(repositories_in_stream):191 - alias       : myapp
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoFileReader.cc(repositories_in_stream):191 - enabled     : 1
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoFileReader.cc(repositories_in_stream):191 - autorefresh : 0
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoFileReader.cc(repositories_in_stream):191 - url         : https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoFileReader.cc(repositories_in_stream):191 - type        : NONE
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoFileReader.cc(repositories_in_stream):191 - priority    : 99
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoFileReader.cc(repositories_in_stream):191 - gpgcheck    : D(Y) repoD(Y)* sig? pkgD(Y)*
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoFileReader.cc(repositories_in_stream):191 - filePath:     /etc/zypp/repos.d/myapp.repo
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoFileReader.cc(repositories_in_stream):191
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] PathInfo.cc(dirForEach):553 readdir /var/cache/zypp/raw
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] PathInfo.cc(dirForEach):553 readdir /var/cache/zypp/solv
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] PathInfo.cc(dirForEach):553 readdir /var/cache/zypp/packages
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(init_knownRepositories):889 end construct known repos
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypper] refresh.cc(execute):132 going to refresh repositories
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypper++] basecommand.cc(defaultSystemSetup):163 FLAGS:[InitTarget]
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypper] repos.cc(init_target):981 Initializing target
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] ZYppImpl.cc(initializeTarget):122 initTarget( /)
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb] librpmDb.cc(globalInit):148 librpm init done: (_target:x86_64-linux) (_dbpath:/usr/lib/sysimage/rpm)
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb] RpmDb.cc(initDatabase):345 Calling initDatabase: '(/)/var/lib/rpm'
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb] librpmDb.cc(unblockAccess):344 Unblock access
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] librpmDb.cc(DbDirInfo):522 '(/)/var/lib/rpm':
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] librpmDb.cc(DbDirInfo):522   Dir:    /var/lib/rpm{d 0755 0/0}
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] librpmDb.cc(DbDirInfo):522   V4:     /var/lib/rpm/Packages{- 0644 0/0 size 105418752}
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] librpmDb.cc(DbDirInfo):522   V3:     /var/lib/rpm/packages.rpm{[2-No such file or directory]}
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] librpmDb.cc(DbDirInfo):522   V3ToV4: /var/lib/rpm/packages.rpm3{[2-No such file or directory]}
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb] RpmDb.cc(internal_initDatabase):468 Found rpm4 database in /var/lib/rpm{d 0755 0/0}
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] RpmDb.cc(internal_initDatabase):485 Initial state: V4(X--)V3(---): '(/)/var/lib/rpm'[librpmDb CLOSED '(/)/var/lib/rpm']
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb] librpmDb.cc(dbAccess):240 Set new database location: '(/)/var/lib/rpm'
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] librpmDb.cc(D):100 DBACCESS {NULL(/)/var/lib/rpm}
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] RpmDb.cc(internal_initDatabase):504 Access state: V4(X--)V3(---): '(/)/var/lib/rpm'[ReferenceCounted(@0x55c45d95a520<=1){NULL(/)/var/lib/rpm}]
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] librpmDb.cc(dbRelease):311 dbRelease: release, outstanding 0
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb] RpmDb.cc(initDatabase):426 Synchronizing keys with zypp keyring
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb] RpmDb.cc(syncTrustedKeys):961 Going to sync trusted keys...
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] librpmDb.cc(D):100 DBACCESS {NULL(/)/var/lib/rpm}
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] librpmDb.cc(dbRelease):311 dbRelease: release, outstanding 0
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] RpmDb.cc(computeKeyRingSync):941 gpg-pubkey-307e3d54-5aaa90a5 R_
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] RpmDb.cc(computeKeyRingSync):941 gpg-pubkey-39db7c82-5847eb1f R_
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] RpmDb.cc(computeKeyRingSync):941 gpg-pubkey-3dbdc284-53674dd4 R_
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb] RpmDb.cc(syncTrustedKeys):993 Rpm keys to export into zypp trusted keyring: 3
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb] RpmDb.cc(syncTrustedKeys):994 Zypp trusted keys to import into rpm database: 0
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb] RpmDb.cc(syncTrustedKeys):1000 Exporting rpm keyring into zypp trusted keyring
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] librpmDb.cc(D):100 DBACCESS {NULL(/)/var/lib/rpm}
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp::gpg++] KeyManager.cc(createForOpenPGP):239 createForOpenPGP(/var/tmp/zypp.Ib2BVe/zypp-trusted-kr2ogLop)
2020-04-22 08:40:48 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp::gpg] KeyManager.cc(initGpgme):44 Initialized libgpgme version: 1.10.0
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp::gpg++] KeyManager.cc(createForOpenPGP):239 createForOpenPGP(/var/tmp/zypp.Ib2BVe/zypp-trusted-kr2ogLop)
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp::KeyRing] KeyRing.cc(getData):166 Found keys: {
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp::KeyRing] KeyRing.cc(getData):166   [B88B2FD43DBDC284-53674dd4] [openSUSE Project Signing Key <opensuse@opensuse.org>] [expires: 2024-05-02]
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp::KeyRing] KeyRing.cc(getData):166   [70AF9E8139DB7C82-5847eb1f] [SuSE Package Signing Key <build@suse.de>] [expires: 2020-12-06]
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp::KeyRing] KeyRing.cc(getData):166   [E3A5C360307E3D54-5aaa90a5] [SuSE Package Signing Key <build@suse.de>] [expires: 2022-03-14]
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp::KeyRing] KeyRing.cc(getData):166 }
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp::KeyRing] KeyRing.cc(publicKeyExists):366 Found key [3dbdc284] in keyring /var/tmp/zypp.Ib2BVe/zypp-trusted-kr2ogLop
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp::KeyRing] KeyRing.cc(publicKeyExists):366 Found key [39db7c82] in keyring /var/tmp/zypp.Ib2BVe/zypp-trusted-kr2ogLop
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp::KeyRing] KeyRing.cc(publicKeyExists):366 Found key [307e3d54] in keyring /var/tmp/zypp.Ib2BVe/zypp-trusted-kr2ogLop
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] PathInfo.cc(unlink):659 unlink /var/tmp/zypp.Ib2BVe/TmpFile.qSZWmK
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] TmpPath.cc(~Impl):78 TmpPath cleaned up /var/tmp/zypp.Ib2BVe/TmpFile.qSZWmK{- 0600 0/0 size 2556}
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb++] librpmDb.cc(dbRelease):311 dbRelease: release, outstanding 0
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb] RpmDb.cc(syncTrustedKeys):1057 Trusted keys synced.
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [librpmDb] RpmDb.cc(initDatabase):435 InitDatabase: RpmDb[V4(X--)V3(---): '(/)/var/lib/rpm']
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] HistoryLog.cc(setRoot):173 installation log file /var/log/zypp/history
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] TargetImpl.cc(TargetImpl):698 Initialized target on /
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] PathInfo.cc(dirForEach):553 readdir /etc/products.d
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] TargetImpl.cc(buildCache):853 Read cookie: /var/cache/zypp/solv/@System/cookie{- 0644 0/0 size 52}
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] TargetImpl.cc(buildCache):860 Read cookie: /var/cache/zypp/solv/@System/cookie says: uptodate
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypper] refresh.cc(refreshRepository):147 going to refresh repo 'myapp'
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypper] refresh.cc(refreshRepository):154 calling refreshMetadata
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(checkIfToRefreshMetadata):971 Going to try to check whether refresh is needed for https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/ (NONE)
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(probeCache):1499 going to probe the cached repo at /var/cache/zypp/raw/myapp
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(probeCache):1510 Probed cached type plaindir at /var/cache/zypp/raw/myapp
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <2> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoStatus.cc(fromCookieFile):114 No cookie file /var/cache/zypp/raw/myapp/cookie
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(checkIfToRefreshMetadata):979 No cached metadata, going to refresh
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(checkIfToRefreshMetadata):971 Going to try to check whether refresh is needed for https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/ (NONE)
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(probeCache):1499 going to probe the cached repo at /var/cache/zypp/raw/myapp
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(probeCache):1510 Probed cached type plaindir at /var/cache/zypp/raw/myapp
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <2> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoStatus.cc(fromCookieFile):114 No cookie file /var/cache/zypp/raw/myapp/cookie
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(checkIfToRefreshMetadata):979 No cached metadata, going to refresh
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(refreshMetadata):1110 Going to refresh metadata from https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(probe):1410 going to probe the repo type at https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/ ()
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] MediaAccess.cc(open):117 Trying scheme 'https'
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] MediaCurl.cc(MediaCurl):549 MediaCurl::MediaCurl(https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/, )
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] MediaMultiCurl.cc(MediaMultiCurl):1164 MediaMultiCurl::MediaMultiCurl(https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/, )
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] MediaAccess.cc(open):197 Opened: https(https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/ not attached; localRoot "")
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaManager.cc(open):258 Opened new media access using id 1 to https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaSetAccess.cc(provide):253 Going to try to provide  file /repodata/repomd.xml from media number 1
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaManager.cc(attach):376 attach(id=1)
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaHandler.cc(createAttachPoint):391 Create attach point: attach root is not a writable directory: '/var/adm/mount'
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaHandler.cc(createAttachPoint):400 Look for orphaned attach points in /var/tmp{d 1777 0/0}
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] PathInfo.cc(dirForEach):553 readdir /var/tmp
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] MediaHandler.cc(createAttachPoint):374 Created default attach point /var/tmp/AP_0xpYFn8X
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] ProductFileReader.cc(parse):219 +++/etc/products.d/baseproduct[g___]
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Reader.cc(Reader):113 Start Parsing /etc/products.d/baseproduct[g___]
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Reader.cc(~Reader):137 Done Parsing /etc/products.d/baseproduct[_eF_]
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] ProductFileReader.cc(parse):245 ---0 - /etc/products.d/baseproduct[_eF_]
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] ProxyInfoLibproxy.cc(getProxyFactory):66 Build Libproxy Factory from /etc/sysconfig/proxy
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaCurl.cc(setupEasy):776 Enabling HTTP authentication methods: digest,basic (CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH=3)
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaCurl.cc(setupEasy):829 Proxy: not explicitly set
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaCurl.cc(setupEasy):830 Proxy: libcurl may look into the environment
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] PathInfo.cc(chmod):1051 assert_file_mode 00600 /var/lib/YaST2/cookieschmod /var/lib/YaST2/cookies 00600
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] MediaHandler.cc(attach):691 Attached: https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/ attached; localRoot "/var/tmp/AP_0xpYFn8X"
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaManager.cc(checkDesired):96 checkDesired(1): desired (report by zypp::media::NoVerifier)
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaManager.cc(checkDesired):98 checkDesired(1): desired (cached)
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaCurl.cc(doGetDoesFileExist):1190 /repodata/repomd.xml
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaCurl.cc(doGetDoesFileExist):1200 URL: https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/repodata/repomd.xml
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] MediaCurl.cc(doGetDoesFileExist):1281 perform code: 22 [ HTTP response code said error ]
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <5> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Exception.cc(log):166 MediaCurl.cc(evaluateCurlCode):1119 THROW:    File '/repodata/repomd.xml' not found on medium 'https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/'
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaManager.cc(checkDesired):98 checkDesired(1): desired (cached)
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaSetAccess.cc(provide):253 Going to try to provide  file /content from media number 1
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaManager.cc(checkDesired):98 checkDesired(1): desired (cached)
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaCurl.cc(doGetDoesFileExist):1190 /content
2020-04-22 08:40:49 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaCurl.cc(doGetDoesFileExist):1200 URL: https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/content
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] MediaCurl.cc(doGetDoesFileExist):1281 perform code: 22 [ HTTP response code said error ]
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <5> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Exception.cc(log):166 MediaCurl.cc(evaluateCurlCode):1119 THROW:    File '/content' not found on medium 'https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/'
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaManager.cc(checkDesired):98 checkDesired(1): desired (cached)
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaManager.cc(close):288 Close to access handler using id 1 requested
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaHandler.cc(release):751 Request to release attached media https<https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/>, use count=1
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaHandler.cc(release):758 Releasing media https<https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/>
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] MediaHandler.cc(disconnect):730 Disconnected: https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/ attached; localRoot "/var/tmp/AP_0xpYFn8X"
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaHandler.cc(removeAttachPoint):181 MediaHandler - checking if to remove attach point
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] PathInfo.cc(recursive_rmdir):426 recursive_rmdir /var/tmp/AP_0xpYFn8X
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] MediaHandler.cc(removeAttachPoint):193 Deleted default attach point /var/tmp/AP_0xpYFn8X
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] MediaHandler.cc(release):812 Released: https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/ not attached; localRoot ""
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] MediaAccess.cc(close):248 Close: https(https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/ not attached; localRoot "") (OK)
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaHandler.cc(release):744 Request to release media - not attached; eject ''
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] MediaHandler.cc(removeAttachPoint):181 MediaHandler - checking if to remove attach point
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(probe):1488 Probed type NONE at https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/ ()
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <5> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Exception.cc(log):166 RepoManager.cc(refreshMetadata):1191 THROW:    [myapp|https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/] Repository type can't be determined.
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp] PathInfo.cc(recursive_rmdir):426 recursive_rmdir /var/cache/zypp/raw/myappZdRqwc
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <1> opensuse(10650) [zypp++] TmpPath.cc(~Impl):78 TmpPath cleaned up /var/cache/zypp/raw/myappZdRqwc{d 0755 0/0}
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <5> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Exception.cc(log):166 RepoManager.cc(refreshMetadata):1205 CAUGHT:   [myapp|https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/] Repository type can't be determined.
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <3> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(refreshMetadata):1206 Trying another url...
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <3> opensuse(10650) [zypp] RepoManager.cc(refreshMetadata):1218 No more urls...
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <5> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Exception.cc(log):166 RepoManager.cc(refreshMetadata):1219 THROW:    [myapp|https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/] Valid metadata not found at specified URL
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <5> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Exception.cc(log):166 History:
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <5> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Exception.cc(log):166  - [myapp|https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/] Repository type can't be determined.
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <5> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Exception.cc(log):166
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <5> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Exception.cc(log):166 repos.cc(refresh_raw_metadata):383 CAUGHT:   [myapp|https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/] Valid metadata not found at specified URL
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <5> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Exception.cc(log):166 History:
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <5> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Exception.cc(log):166  - [myapp|https://myuser@rpm.myapp.com/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/] Repository type can't be determined.
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <5> opensuse(10650) [zypp] Exception.cc(log):166
2020-04-22 08:40:50 <3> opensuse(10650) [zypper] refresh.cc(refreshRepositories):263 Skipping repository 'myapp' because of the above error.
```

Any idea what else to check would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: cross-posted from serverfault

Answer (score 0):

Did you try disabling the Temporary Login Suspension ?
Rel
https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-disable-temporary-login-suspension/

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/General+Security+Settings#GeneralSecuritySettings-UserLockandLoginSuspension

https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-22284?focusedCommentId=216396&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-216396