# JFrog Artifactory intermittently rejects authentication with 403 forbidden

Tags: http-headers, artifactory

I am having a hard time configuring `zypper` clients (SLES and OpenSUSE) to work with our `RPM Repository` in [JFrog](https://jfrog.com/) due to some "authentication" issues. At first, I thought it was just an issue with `zypper` and opensuse so I first focused on our efforts to make things work with zypper. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61589586/opensuse-%60zypper%60-error-valid-metadata-not-found-at-specified-url-repository-ty) was the previous question.

But these authentication-related errors come up every now and then with `yum` clients as well (centOS), although not that often.

So I tried doing `man-in-the-middle` to see what's happening under the hood, and this is the sequence with `zypper`:

---

### Scenario 1 - successful authentication

The following is the sequence of a `zypper refresh --repo myrepo`:

(1) `zypper` sends an HTTP `HEAD` request with the `base64`-encoded `username:`:

```
HEAD /myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/repodata/repomd.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: rpm.example.com
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6
User-Agent: ZYpp 17.19.0 (curl 7.60.0) openSUSE-Leap-15.1-x86_64
Accept: */*
Connection: close
```

(2) `jfrog` responds with HTTP `401 Unauthorized` with the `WWW-Authenticate` header:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 28 May 2020 08:20:04 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Connection: close
Server: Artifactory/7.4.3 70403900
X-Artifactory-Id: 2148103ba10eacbb:-16f1c4c1:172093a231a:-8000
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: artifactory-server
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"
```

(3) `zypper` sends another HTTP `HEAD` request, this time with the `base64`-encoded `username:password`:

```
HEAD /myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/repodata/repomd.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: rpm.example.com
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
User-Agent: ZYpp 17.19.0 (curl 7.60.0) openSUSE-Leap-15.1-x86_64
Accept: */*
Connection: close
```

(4) `jfrog` finally responds with an HTTP `200`.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 28 May 2020 08:20:04 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 1394
Connection: close
Server: Artifactory/7.4.3 70403900
X-Artifactory-Id: 2148103ba10eacbb:-16f1c4c1:172093a231a:-8000
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: artifactory-server
Last-Modified: Fri, 08 May 2020 10:25:19 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Artifactory-Filename: repomd.xml
Cache-Control: no-store
```

These are logged by Artifactory:

`artifactory-request.log`:

```
2020-05-28T08:20:34.566Z [5f78297c2aeabaa8] [DENIED LOGIN]   for client : username / 213.1.1.1. 
2020-05-28T08:20:34.870Z [570978212a5318e3] [ACCEPTED DOWNLOAD] myapp-release-rpm-cache:stable/myapp/2019/3/repodata/repomd.xml  for client : username / 213.1.1.1.
```

`artifactory-access.log`:

```
2020-05-28T08:20:34.566Z|5f78297c2aeabaa8|213.2.2.2|non_authenticated_user|HEAD|/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/repodata/repomd.xml|401|-1|0|8|ZYpp 17.19.0 (curl 7.60.0) openSUSE-Leap-15.1-x86_64
2020-05-28T08:20:34.721Z|8018b7cbc9c424e8|213.2.2.2|username|HEAD|/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/repodata/repomd.xml|200|-1|1394|3|ZYpp 17.19.0 (curl 7.60.0) openSUSE-Leap-15.1-x86_64
2020-05-28T08:20:34.870Z|570978212a5318e3|213.2.2.2|username|GET|/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/repodata/repomd.xml|200|-1|1394|2|ZYpp 17.19.0 (curl 7.60.0) openSUSE-Leap-15.1-x86_64
...
```

So basically, `zypper` comes in with a `HEAD` request, JFrog says "you're not authenticated", `zypper` responds back and tries to authenticate, and finally JFrog authenticates zypper. Makes sense so far.

---

### Scenario 2 - 403 forbidden

Do some work, then run the same `zypper refresh --repo myrepo` command after a few minutes or so, and here is the result:

(1) `zypper` sends an HTTP `HEAD` request with the `base64`-encoded `username:`:

```
HEAD /myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/repodata/repomd.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: rpm.example.com
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6
User-Agent: ZYpp 17.19.0 (curl 7.60.0) openSUSE-Leap-15.1-x86_64
Accept: */*
Connection: close
```

(2) `jfrog` responds with HTTP `401 Unauthorized` with the `WWW-Authenticate` header:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 28 May 2020 08:30:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Connection: close
Server: Artifactory/7.4.3 70403900
X-Artifactory-Id: 2148103ba10eacbb:-16f1c4c1:172093a231a:-8000
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: artifactory-server
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"
```

(3) `zypper` sends another HTTP `HEAD` request, this time with the `base64`-encoded `username:password`:

```
HEAD /myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/repodata/repomd.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: rpm.example.com
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
User-Agent: ZYpp 17.19.0 (curl 7.60.0) openSUSE-Leap-15.1-x86_64
Accept: */*
Connection: close
```

(4) this time, `jfrog` responds with `403 Forbidden` instead of `200 OK`.

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Thu, 28 May 2020 08:30:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Connection: close
Server: Artifactory/7.4.3 70403900
X-Artifactory-Id: 2148103ba10eacbb:-16f1c4c1:172093a231a:-8000
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: artifactory-server
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"
```

`artifactory-request.log`:

```
2020-05-28T08:30:44.496Z [46c81a2450623166] [DENIED LOGIN]   for client : username / 213.1.1.1.
2020-05-28T08:30:44.630Z [769ed41c652daa7a] [DENIED LOGIN]   for client : username / 213.1.1.1.
```

`artifactory-access.log`:

```
2020-05-28T08:30:44.496Z|46c81a2450623166|213.2.2.2|non_authenticated_user|HEAD|/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/repodata/repomd.xml|401|-1|0|9|ZYpp 17.19.0 (curl 7.60.0) openSUSE-Leap-15.1-x86_64
2020-05-28T08:30:44.630Z|769ed41c652daa7a|213.2.2.2|non_authenticated_user|HEAD|/myapp-release-rpm/stable/myapp/2019/3/repodata/repomd.xml|403|-1|0|1|ZYpp 17.19.0 (curl 7.60.0) openSUSE-Leap-15.1-x86_64
```

---

Notice that zypper sends the same `Authorization` header value when asked to authenticate, but on the second scenario, `JFrog` fails to authenticate the request.

Did anybody have this same issue with JFrog before? We are guessing this is an issue with JFrog 7 since ours was just recently upgraded, but there is no way for us to verify this. And unfortunately for us, we are on the paid plan which doesn't even have a support license.

Any suggestions and comments will be very much appreciated.

## Additional information

It might be worth-noting that `yum` clients (centos and rhel) do not have this exact issue with `JFrog Artifactory`, and it's most likely because yum always sends the username and password hash in the HTTP header, avoiding the `401 Unauthorized` re-authentication sequence.

## More details

I submitted a [bug report](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-22284) to JFrog last May, and so far did not get any update.

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting the baseurl to:

```
http://username:apikey@some.url/artifactory
```

?

Comment: Hello, although this works with `curl`, it does not work with the `zypper` client.

Comment: Is this HA setup or single node? Were there any changes made to groups or permissions?

Comment: It's a single-node Artifactory. There was a recent upgrade, but this issue was observed (although not investigated as detailed as right now) for a long time on `zypper` clients.